# how to load UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I have a code that currently loads a NIB file like below :

`Login *monLogin = [[[Login alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:monLogin animated:YES];`

but the app is TabBar App (xcode template) and is suppose to also load the bottom menu. 
how can I load this NIB file with the UITabBarController included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7375002/470879) might help.  But now I'm a little confused about what you're attempting to do.  Let me know and I can help you further.

The modal view will not include the TabBar because a TabBar owns the view controllers represented by each tab.  Why do you want the TabBar included in the login view?  If you really want a TabBar in your modal view, then you'll need to put your 'log in' view controller inside a TabBar view controller, and then present the TabBar view controller modally.

However, I'd recommend that you have the TabBar in the main part of your app, and present the 'log in' view modally without a TabBar included.  Once the user is finished logging in, you can dismiss the 'log in' view, which returns the user to the main part of your app.

To dismiss the modal view controller, set up a delegate system (look through the utility app template to see how this works). If setting up your own delegate protocol is too difficult at the moment, then you can use a workaround in the mean time.  In your 'log in' view controller code, after the user has logged in successfully, you can send a message to your parent view controller (the one that presented the modal view) to dismiss it's modal view (your 'log in' view).

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This is bad form though.  Once you're up to it you should use a delegate callback to have the parent view controller dismiss the modal view.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, this actually worked perfectly fine :). now do you mind telling me a bit more about what exactly is the better way? or can you link me to an article or a tutorial to use a delegate callback to have the parent view controller dismiss the modal view?

thanks alot

Comment: See the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS - Modal View Controllers section.  It talks about delegation in relation to Modal View Controllers.  Here are some basic guides to writing your own delegation protocol:  http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html  and  http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/07/your-own-delegation-protocol/

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been realy helpful. I will post a comment here if I needed your help again.

Comment: No worries.  Your confusion on this matter might be helped more with a clearer understanding of object creation and ownership, in relation to view controllers.  If you want to know more, write a question detailing your understanding so far, and I can help clear up any issues you might have.  Cheers, Matt