# how to add UItabBarController as a subview

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I have made a TabBar project using xcode's templates and I have the tabbar in the mainwindow.xib ofcourse.

once after the user logs into the app, I redirect them to a page called notifications, `[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];` but the tabbar doesnt show up.

now how can I either include the tabbar in the code above or get the tabbar from mainWindow.xib and display it once the UIView is loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your 'log in' view display the TabBar?  If so, that's because your 'log in' view controller is a child of the TabBar view controller.  Your modal view does not show the TabBar because it's controller is not a child of the TabBar view controller.

You may want to reconsider the design of you app.  A modal view controller is usually presented as temporary deviation from the main workflow.  See the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS - [Modal View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

You could swap things around.  Have the main contents of your app in the TabBar, and upon the app launch, if the user is not already logged in, present your 'log in' view as a Modal View.  Then dismiss it once the user logs in.

Comment: Hey, when the app loads and if the user is logged in I don't have a problem because notifications is a child of the tab bar, but when the login is displayed an user logs in, I redirect them to notifications and there the tab bar doesn't show up

Comment: How are you 'redirecting' them to the notifications view?  And how are you showing the log in view?

Comment: If 'redirect' means instantiating and pushing another copy of your notifications view controller (not a child of the TabBar) on top of the log in view controller, then this is wrong.  If your log in view controller was presented modally on top of your notifications view controller then you need to dismiss it to return to the original notifications view (a child of the TabBar).